# Sutton & Barto Book: a doubt on formalism

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, reinforcement-learning

I have a doubt on the probability p(s' , r |s, a) defined at page 48 of Sutton & Barto Book:

- at the end of page 48 it reads: "The dynamics function p : S x R x S x A -> [0, 1] is an ordinary deterministic function of four arguments. The ‘|’ in the middle of it comes from the notation for conditional probability but here it just reminds us that p specifies a probability distribution for each choice of s and a".

This appears (to me) to suggest that p is somehow different from an actual conditional probability. However when the expectation E is computed it seems that p is used as if it actually were a conditional probability, (e.g. 3.19 at page 63).

[image: Conditional Expectation]

Does this mean that for all the practical computations we can assume that p can be used, in fact, as a conditional probability?

Comment: Would it help to change the notation from $p(s^\prime,r\mid s,a)$ to, say, $p_{s,a}(s^\prime, r)$? Then there would be no worries about conditional probabilities.

Comment: Hi whuber and thank you for your answer. In fact some other textbooks don't use Sutton & Barto formalism. However, going back to Sutton & Barto, in the (3.19) formula (see blue arrow), the expectation appears to refer explicitly conditional probability, that is E[....|St = s, At=a]. Hence my doubt.

Comment: Can you please link or reference that book?

Comment: I really don't understand the question: the book *explicitly* states this is not a conditional probability and there is no apparent use of conditional probabilities in the boxed equations.

Comment: Hi kjetil and thank you for your answer. You can find the book here:
http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html

Comment: In Sutton & Barto book it is stated that the vertical sign '|' in (′,∣,) doesn't stand for conditional probability but only means that summing over s' and r gives 1. This meaning doesn't seem to apply (or at least I don't see how) to the above Expectation, so I guess it is a conditional expectation hence requiring in its definition conditional probability (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation).

Comment: After considering my latest comment I've come to think that '|' in the expectation formula only links to some of the 'model describing' probabilities introduced in the book and which one depends by the number and identity of the arguments on the right side of '|'; on the other hand 'pi' links the expectation to a stochastic policy. I guess what I found a little confusing is linking expectation to probabilities in different ways.